# SQL Server Window Function assign groups by order based on whether or not the row before or after is of the same type

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Is there a way in SQL server to use a window function to order by a column, and then assign groups based on whether or not the row before or after is of the same type?

Suppose for table [tbl1]

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 ORDER BY SEQ
```

Produces this output.

```
SEQ  Type
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    a
5    c
6    c
```

Can you produce this result with a window function?

```
SEQ  Type  Group
1    a     1
2    a     1
3    b     2
4    a     3
5    c     4
6    c     4
```

Notice that row 4 is being treated as a separate group because rows 3 or row 5 are not type 'a'.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a difference of row numbers.  Here is one method that produces sequential numbers

```
select seq, type,
       dense_rank() over (order by grp, type)
from (select t.*, 
             (row_number() over (order by seq) -
              row_number() over (partition by type order by seq)
             ) as grp
      from tbl1 t
     ) t;
```

Note that this allows gaps in `seq`.  If there are no gaps, you can replace the first `row_number()` with just `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different solution based on `LAG` and `SUM` with `OVER (ORDER BY ...)` window functions, available from SQL Server 2012 onwards:

```
SELECT SEQ, Type, SUM(flag) OVER(ORDER BY SEQ) + 1 AS [Group]
FROM (
   SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(Type) OVER(ORDER BY SEQ) <> Type THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END AS flag                   
   FROM #tbl1 ) t
```

This subquery:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(Type) OVER(ORDER BY SEQ) <> Type THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END AS flag                  
FROM #tbl1
```

produces this output (based on the sample data of the OP):

```
SEQ Type flag
----------------
1   a    0
2   a    0
3   b    1
4   a    1
5   c    1
6   c    0
```

`flag` is an indication of changes in `Type`. The outer query calculates group number as the *running total* of `flag`.

**Output:**

```
SEQ Type Group
--------------
1   a    1
2   a    1
3   b    2
4   a    3
5   c    4
6   c    4
```